# IWbemClassObject Get successfully, while Put with Error: ERROR_SXS_KEY_NOT_FOUND 140007

Tags: c++, wmi

The main goal of the code is to customize the InitialSize and MaximumSize of the virtual memory pagefile.

ENV: windows Server 2008

Code:

```
...
...
IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = NULL;
ULONG uReturn = 0;

while(pEnumerator)
{
    HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE,1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);
    VARIANT initial_size;
    VARIANT maximum_size;


    //InitialSize 
    pclsObj->Get(L"InitialSize", 0, &initial_size, 0, 0);

    //get the maximumsize of the pagefile
    //MaximumSize  
    pclsObj->Get(L"MaximumSize", 0, &maximum_size, 0, 0); //successfully


    //use the put to adjust the pagefile size

    VARIANT in_initialsize;
    VariantInit(&in_initialsize);
    in_initialsize.vt = VT_I4;
    in_initialsize.iVal = 13000;

    //set the initialsize of the pagefile
    hr = pclsObj->Put(L"InitialSize", 0, &in_initialsize, 0); //failed with 14007
        ...
        ...
}
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use another solution, to get the instance `GetObject` and at last. has to execute the Put operation; something like the following:

```
...
l_pSVC->PutInstance(l_pinObj, WBEM_FLAG_UPDATE_ONLY, NULL, NULL);
...
```